# Morse Code with Arduino

Tags: string, arduino

I am learning to code Arduino and so to do that, I tried to make a Morse code converter from English. This is my code and I am facing the issue below:

```
   Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\Kunal Gehlot\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Morse_CODE\Morse_CODE.ino: In function 'void setup()':

Morse_CODE:16: error: request for member 'length' in 'in', which is of non-class type 'char [28]'

   for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {

                          ^

Morse_CODE:18: error: request for member 'lentgh' in 'in', which is of non-class type 'char [28]'

   n = in.lentgh[i];

          ^

exit status 1
request for member 'length' in 'in', which is of non-class type 'char [28]'

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Here's my code:

```
int Speaker1 = 4;
int Speaker2 = 6;
int LED = 2;
int Relay = 12;
char n = 0;
char in[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";

void setup() {
  pinMode(Speaker1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Speaker2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
  for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
    n = in.lentgh[i];
    switch (n) {
      case 'A' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'B' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'C' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'D' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'E' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'F' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'G' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'H' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'I' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'J' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'K' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'L' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'M' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'N' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'O' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'P':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'Q':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'R':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'S':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'T':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'U':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'V':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'W':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'X':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'Y':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case 'Z':
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
      case ' ' :
        delay (700);
        break;
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

My sole aim for this project would be to take input text from Serial monitor in caps and break it into each individual letter, where I'd also be adding symbols to the list and translate it into Morse code in LED, Relay for electric pulse and speaker.

Comment: Where did you get `length`? And what is `in.lentgh[i]` supposed to do?

Comment: Please don't fix questions to become answers, otherwise it is hard for new readers to see what the problem is. As you have done, adding an answer is the correct approach. Thanks!

Comment: Noted and sorry, will take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out in comments, you should use strlen() to find the length of arrays of characters in Arduino. strlen() is part of the standard Arduino libraries, so you can use it without having to add any special #include statements.

If you use sizeof(in), the code will send every character in the buffer, even if the string you're interested in is smaller than the buffer.

For example, suppose in[] = "ABC"; sizeof(in) incorrectly returns 4 because "ABC" has a hidden 0 byte just after the 'C' character.  strlen(in) in that case returns 3, the correct number.

So,

for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
    n = in.lentgh[i];

should instead be

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(in); i++) {
    n = in[i];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using in.lentgh[i], sizeof(in) is supposed to be used in for loop's condition.

solved code :

```
int Speaker1 = 4;
int Speaker2 = 6;
int LED = 2;
int Relay = 12;
char n = '0';
char in[]= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";

void setup() {

  pinMode(Speaker1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Speaker2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(in); i++) {
  delay (1200);
  n = in[i];

    switch (n) {

case 'A' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'B' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'C' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'D' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'E' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'F' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'G' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'H' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'I' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'J' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'K' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'L' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'M' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'N' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'O' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'P' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'Q' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'R' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'S' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'T' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'U' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'V' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'W' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'X' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'Y' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case 'Z' :
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(300);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, HIGH);
        delay(100);
        digitalWrite(Speaker1, LOW);
        delay(300);
        break;
case ' ' :
        delay (700);
        break;
    }


  }


}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is the size of the buffer not necessarily the length of the string. Use `strlen`.

Comment: Doesn't matter.